# How do you specialize a member function inside a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, abstraction, member-functions

Let's say I have the following class:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass : Parent<T>
{
public:
    // I have a function such as this one:
    T DoSomething(const T &t)
    {
        return t.DoSomething(some_data);
    }

    // But `T` might be a pointer, so sometimes I will need something like the following
    // instead (which obviously doesn't work as given):
    T DoSomething(const T &t)
    {
        return new T(t->DoSomething(some_data));
    }

private:
    XYZ some_data;
};
```

I got stuck in a giant mess of template errors trying to implement this in any semi-nice way possible using template specialization.

In the end I came up with this very ugly solution:

```
template <typename T>
class SomeClass : Parent<T>
{
public:
    T DoSomething(const T &x)
    {
        return Specializer<T>::Do(this, x);
    }

private:
    template <typename V>
    struct Specializer {
        static V Do(SomeClass *me, const V &x)
        {
            return x.DoSomething(me->some_data);
        }
    };

    template <typename V>
    struct Specializer<V*> {
        static V* Do(SomeClass *me, const V *&x)
        {
            return new V(x->DoSomething(me->some_data));
        }
    };

    XYZ some_data;
};
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't involve stuffing this function into a dummy class/struct and passing around my `this` pointer?

PS: In reality, this has nothing to do with pointers, but rather with different types of containers. Pointers were just an easy example to use here.

Comment: have you tried with sfinae?

Comment: Which version of C++ are you using? If you're in [tag:c++20], you can use `requires`

Comment: @Human-Compiler - IMHO, you should expand your comment in an answer (making clear that C++20 is required).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid writing any specializations, and use a type trait like [std::is_pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer) along with `if constexpr` to decide what code to execute depending on the whether the type is a pointer type or not:

```
auto DoSomething(const T &t)
{
  if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>)
      return new T(t->DoSomething(some_data));
  else    
      return t.DoSomething(some_data);
}
```

If you don't want to check for whether `T` is a pointer, but want to check something else, you can still use this pattern by dropping in a suitable replacement for `is_pointer`.

Comment: Thanks, though as I mentioned in the "PS", my actual situation is not actually related to pointers. I'm not sure there is anything equivalent to `std::is_pointer_v` that I could use.

Comment: @Matt Go ahead and add the requirements you care about to the question. Writing a trait that checks for those properties will still work nicely with `if constexpr`.

Comment: Actually, this does give me some good ideas. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20), you can clean up the need for any SFINAE, specializations, or `if constexpr` by using [concepts and constraints](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints) instead. This just allows you to define the same function N times with different criteria for its insantiation, which is much more readable IMO.

This is almost the same as the SFINAE approach, but without the need for the awful syntax (no `std::declval`, `decltype`, etc). It also doesn't require all implementations to exist in one function definition like the `if constexpr` approach; all you need is separate function definitions with different `requires` clauses:

```cpp
#include <concepts>

...

template <typename T>
class SomeClass : Parent<T>
{
public:
    // Work for everything that's not specialized
    void DoSomething(const T &t) 
    { 
        std::cout << "Basic overload" << std::endl; 
    }

    // Only work for pointers
    void DoSomething(const T& t) requires(std::is_pointer_v<T>) 
    { 
        std::cout << "Pointer overload" << std::endl; 
    }

    // Only work if T is convertible to SomeType
    void DoSomething(const T& t) requires(std::convertible_to<T, SomeType>) 
    { 
        std::cout << "Convertible to SomeType overload" << std::endl; 
    }

private:
    XYZ some_data;
};
```

<kbd>[Live Example](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YPYsMxKT5)</kbd>

In this approach there are 3 different entries:

- The basic fallback for all templates
- An implementation that works for any pointer type, and
- An implementation that works for any `T` type that may be convertible to `SomeType`

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I have access to C++20 features in the context that prompted this question. However, this seems really useful, and I'll keep it in mine for the future.

Answer (score 1):

What about using SFINAE?

For example

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template <typename>
struct Parent
 { };

using XYZ = int;

template <typename T>
class SomeClass : Parent<T>
 {
   public:
      template <typename U = T>
      auto DoSomething (T const & t)
       -> decltype( std::declval<U>().DoSomething(std::declval<XYZ>()) )
        { std::cout << "ref\n"; return t.DoSomething(some_data); }

      template <typename U = T>
      auto DoSomething (T const & t)
       -> std::remove_reference_t<
             decltype( std::declval<U>()->DoSomething(std::declval<XYZ>()),
                       std::declval<T>() )>
        {
          using V = std::remove_reference_t<decltype(*t)>;

          std::cout << "pnt\n"; return new V(t->DoSomething(some_data));
        }

   private:
      XYZ some_data;
 };

struct foo
 {
   foo (foo*) {}
   foo () {}

   foo DoSomething (int) const { return {}; }
 } ;

int main()
 {
   SomeClass<foo>   sc1;
   SomeClass<foo*>  sc2;

   foo f;

   sc1.DoSomething(f);
   sc2.DoSomething(&f);
 }
```

I mean: what about enabling the first version if, and only if, `T` is a type that supports a `DoSomething(XYZ)` method and enabling the second version if, and only if, `T` is a **pointer** of a type that supports a `DoSomething(XYZ)` method?

Comment: Hmm... `decltype` is not something that I'm experienced with, so I didn't know something like this was possible. I'll try it out, thanks!

Comment: Ok, so I tried this and get the error "functions that differ only in their return type cannot be overloaded", so the sfinae isn't working.

Comment: For sfinae to work the functions need to be templates.

Comment: @Matt - Sorry... sometime I forget that, as observed from yuri kilochek, SFINAE works over template parameter of the element you want to enable/disable. It's more complicated... answer modified to show a full example.

Comment: @yurikilochek - You're absolutely right; sometimes I tend to forget this point. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure than that SFINAE is clearer than OP code though :-/